# HTTP Responses are coming back with quote characters

Tags: c#, http

I have this API endpoint:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage CheckForGameId(string name, string password)
{
    if (name == null || password == null)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
            "One or more of the method arguments was invalid.");
    }
    using (var context = new BattleGameEntities())
    {
        var lobby = context.Lobbies.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LobbyName == name 
            && l.StartedOn == null 
            && !l.AttemptedRemoval);
        if (lobby == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, 
                "No lobby could be found that matched those credentials.");
        }
        if (password == lobby.Password)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lobby.LobbyId);
        }
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, 
       "No lobby could be found that matched those credentials.");
}
```

And I am able to get a response just fine, however, my response object's `responseText` property has values like this:

```
""No lobby could be found that matched those credentials.""
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
"No lobby could be found that matched those credentials."
```

Is there any more semantic / cleaner way of doing this besides scrubbing the message of beginning and ending quote characters?

Comment: I ran it, I can see proper return value with single double quotes around. Where do you see those double double quotes, in debugger?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I just ran into this strange behavior myself.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I just wrote an extension method for the string prototype to "fix" it.